# Distance between a density operator and a pure quantum state.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics

Given density operators $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ and a pure quantum state $|\psi>$. It is promised that $|\psi>$ is in only one of the given density operators. How to find which density operator $|\psi>$ belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that what you are claiming is that $\langle\psi|\rho_i|\psi\rangle\neq 0$ for just one $i\in\{1,2\}$. Hence the criterion you are looking for.